# List with position of certain values of a matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a matrix with `1` and `0` in it. For example:

```
M1 = matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
row.names(M1) <- c(100, 101)
colnames(M1) <- c("A", "B", "C")
M1

    A B C
100 1 0 1
101 0 1 0
```

Now I want to create a list of all the `values=1` in the matrix with the following syntax:

```
"row name"."column name", value
```

In this example the solution I'm looking for would be:

```
100.A, 1
100.C, 1
101.B, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- which(M1==1, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(COL=paste0(rownames(M1)[x[,1]], ".", colnames(M1)[x[,2]], ", ", 1))

#       COL
#1 100.A, 1
#2 101.B, 1
#3 100.C, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
paste0(row.names(M1==1), ".", colnames(M1==1))
```

Or if you want to add 1:

```
data.frame(result = paste0(row.names(M1==1), ".", colnames(M1==1), ", 1"))
```

**EDIT: correct when 1 more than 1 time**

```
result <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(M1)){
  result[[i]] <- data.frame(result = paste0(rep(row.names(M1)[i], length(colnames(M1)[M1[i,]==1])), ".", colnames(M1)[M1[i,]==1], ", 1"))
}
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
result <- unique(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for imput! But I think it dosn't work if the matrix has another structure. For example if there is more than one value in a columne equal 1